# Detect rails from an image using edge detection in matlab

Tags: matlab, edge-detection

I want to detect rails from an image using Matlab. This is the transformed image that I got using some Matlab functions and prewitt edge detection.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7susC.jpg

Now I want to identify the rails, and I am not sure how to start and what algorithm to use. Is there some general approach to this kind of problem? I was thinking about identifying straight lines somehow and see how it goes, but I am not sure how to do that either. Any idea on how to attack this problem would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Have you heard about the [Hough Transform](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/houghlines.html)?

Comment: I didn't, but I will make an research now. Many thanks!